# Which of these jQuery selectors performs better?

Tags: jquery

Performance wise which one is better:

```
 $(".myclass").eq(0)
```

OR

```
 $("a.myclass")
```

Note: If there is only one `<a>` tag having `.myclass`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The second - always use tag names when you can (see rule 2 of the [jQuery performance rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#use-tags-before-classes)).

Answer (score 6):

The second, because it can use the browser's `document.getElementsByTagName()` function that is implemented in C/C++, rather than Javascript.

Also, if there is only a single `a` with `.myclass` consider putting an id on it and doing `$('#myid')`. Fetching by id is the fastest way. It uses `document.getElementById()` which, again, is implemented in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

For more, see [Paul Irish's Anti-patterns](http://paulirish.com/perf/) starting at about slide 19.

Always descend from an ID if you can. Be more specific on the right and more general on the left.

There's a jquery based speed profiler out there that would allow you to test this to see the actual speed differences, but I'm having trouble finding it...

Answer (score 1):

These things are easy to profile using firebug.

```
console.profile();
jQuery('#id');
console.profileEnd();
```

Sometimes it depends upon your dom / which browser your targetting etc etc rather than relying on 'best practise'. Always profile locally to see what works best.